# How can I get info on run time errors for Python modules built with f2py

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

**Edit 3/6:  Sorry, this was a false alarm.  It seems to be working now.  I believe the `-g` flag on gfortran and `--debug-capi` are sufficient after all to generate line numbers for GDB (gnu debugger).  I will make a short answer summarizing how to do this in case it is helpful for others (was a bit of a learning experience for me).  But please feel free to post additional answers that improve on this.  In particular I would be interested in being able to get line numbers without using GDB, if that's possible.**

This must be a common problem but I can't find any answers. The error is in in the Fortran library (what I call `f2.f90` below), but it's a runtime error that isn't triggered until I am using the code via Python.

To make it a little more explicit:

1. I compile several files with `gfortran`:

   ```
   gfortran -c f1.f90 f2.f90
   ```
2. I generate a module with `f2py`:

   ```
   f2py -c f1.o f2.o -m main main.f90
   ```
3. In python:

   ```
   import main
   ```
4. In python, call subroutine main, inside of main:

   ```
   main.main()
   ```

I can get this to work successfully but when I play around with `f2.f90` I will often have some error, and when that happens it's in step 4 and will crash python and only give me the option to close it.  Unfortunately I get no information about what line in `f2.f90` caused the problem or any other info.

So, pretty simple question, is there a way I can cause step 4 to give me some basic info about the run time crash?  Mainly the line number of the problem.

I've tried adding `-g -fbacktrace` to gfortran call and `--debug-capi` to `f2py` and then using `gdb python` with backtrace.  This looks somewhat promising as it at least tells me that the offending file is `f2.f90`, but not the line number.  If I try "backtrace full" it will tell me `No symbol table info available` which is probably where the line number info is held?

Comment: Can you show the error messages you are getting now? Did you try compiling with `-fcheck=all`(may affect performance)?

Comment: I'm not at my work computer now so can't now but will do it later.  I think it's a segfault.  But to be clear, I'm not really concerned about this specific error.  I know it's a runtime error resulting b/c I haven't loaded data yet.  I'm just concerned about how I can get line numbers for run time errors in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief, this combo of flags seems to allow gdb to produce line number of any runtime errors in `f1.f90` or `f2.f90`:

```
C:\> gfortran -g -fbacktrace -c f1.f90 f2.f90
C:\> f2py --debug-capi -c -I. f1.o f2.o -m main main.f90
C:\> gdb python

(gdb) run main.py
```

Where `main.py` imports/calls `main.f90` which is using/calling `f1.f90` and `f2.f90`.  Can then do backtrace to get some additional info.

```
(gdb) backtrace
```